# How do I add a sidebar to the Slash Octopress theme?

Tags: themes, octopress

I am using the [Slash theme](http://zespia.tw/Octopress-Theme-Slash/) for Octopress.

Right now, the entire page just has datestamp in left column and post in the middle.

In my `_config.yml`, I have tried both this:

```
default_asides: [asides/about.html]
```

and this:

```
default_asides: [custom/asides/about.html]
```

I have that file in my `source/_includes/custom/asides/`

But it doesn't show that aside at all.

This is the content of that `about.html`:

```
<section>
  <h1>About Me</h1>
  <p>A little something about me.</p>
</section>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a theme called fabric which also doesn't have a sidebar.

And I also find that only modify _config.yml doesn't work.

But I find this in the classic theme's `source/_layouts/post`

```
 {% unless page.sidebar == false %}
 <aside class="sidebar">
   {% if site.post_asides.size %}
 {% include_array post_asides %}
   {% else %}
     {% include_array default_asides %}
   {% endif %}
 </aside>
```

so it's clear that you also need to add the similar code to your new theme if you want to have a sidebar.

Hope this can give you some insight.  ^_^